# Android application using GridView and BaseAdapter

Tags: java, android, gridview, baseadapter

I am trying to run the Android App on my emulator/device.

There is no compile time error , but the app crashes when run on the device/emulator and

"Unfortunately, GridViewMapExample has stopped" message id displayed on the screen.

MainActivity.java

```java
package com.example.gridviewmapexample;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    GridView grid;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);// step 3
        grid.setAdapter(new NikAdapter(this));

    }

}

class Country {
    String countryName;
    int imageId;

    Country(String countryName, int imageId) {
        this.countryName = countryName;
        this.imageId = imageId;

    }
}

class NikAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<Country> list;
    Context c;

    NikAdapter(Context c) {
        this.c = c;
        list = new ArrayList<Country>();
        Resources res = c.getResources();
        String[] tempCountryNames = res.getStringArray(R.array.country_names);
        int[] countryImages = { R.drawable.germany_flag, R.drawable.india_flag,
                R.drawable.italy_flag, R.drawable.norway_flag,
                R.drawable.pakistan_flag, R.drawable.saudi_arabia_flag };
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            Country tempCountry = new Country(tempCountryNames[i],
                    countryImages[i]);
            list.add(tempCountry);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        ImageView myImageView;

        ViewHolder(View v) {
            myImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = view;
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) c
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAUNCHER_APPS_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(row);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        Country temp = list.get(i);
        holder.myImageView.setImageResource(temp.imageId);
        holder.myImageView.setTag(temp);
        return row;
    }

}
```

strings.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">GridViewMapExample</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>

     <string-array name="country_names">
        <item>Germany</item>
        <item>India</item>
        <item>Italy</item>
        <item>Norway</item>
        <item>Pakistan</item>
        <item>Saudi Arabia </item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

single_item.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/india_flag" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.gridviewmapexample.MainActivity" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:columnWidth="120dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm getting the following stack trace and after searching for quite some time now, I still have no idea what is causing it.

```
        04-26 18:09:01.944: D/ServiceManager(22760): The name of the service is display
        04-26 18:09:01.946: D/ServiceManager(22760): The name of the service is dropbox
        04-26 18:09:01.949: D/jdwp(22760): sendBufferedRequest : len=0x57
        04-26 18:09:01.952: W/asset(22760): AssetManager-->addDefaultAssets CIP path not exsit!
        04-26 18:09:01.954: D/ServiceManager(22760): The name of the service is package
        04-26 18:09:01.962: D/ServiceManager(22760): The name of the service is connectivity
        04-26 18:09:02.031: D/ServiceManager(22760): The name of the service is window
        04-26 18:09:02.033: D/ServiceManager(22760): The name of the service is accessibility
        04-26 18:09:02.063: D/ServiceManager(22760): The name of the service is theme
        04-26 18:09:02.067: W/asset(22760): AssetManager-->addDefaultAssets CIP path not exsit!
        04-26 18:09:02.068: D/ThemeManager(22760): contextandroid.app.ContextImpl@41296280
        04-26 18:09:02.069: D/ThemeManager(22760): create ThemeManager object
        04-26 18:09:02.070: D/ThemeManager(22760): Res_clear()
        04-26 18:09:02.107: W/asset(22760): AssetManager-->addDefaultAssets CIP path not exsit!
        04-26 18:09:02.138: I/dalvikvm(22760): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onNestedScrollAccepted, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted
        04-26 18:09:02.138: W/dalvikvm(22760): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11343: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onNestedScrollAccepted (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/View;I)V
        04-26 18:09:02.138: D/dalvikvm(22760): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
        04-26 18:09:02.139: I/dalvikvm(22760): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onStopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onStopNestedScroll
        04-26 18:09:02.139: W/dalvikvm(22760): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11349: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onStopNestedScroll (Landroid/view/View;)V
        04-26 18:09:02.140: D/dalvikvm(22760): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
        04-26 18:09:02.142: I/dalvikvm(22760): Could not find method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.stopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setHideOnContentScrollEnabled
        04-26 18:09:02.143: W/dalvikvm(22760): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9037: Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout;.stopNestedScroll ()V
        04-26 18:09:02.143: D/dalvikvm(22760): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000e
        04-26 18:09:02.154: I/dalvikvm(22760): Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
        04-26 18:09:02.154: W/dalvikvm(22760): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 365: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
        04-26 18:09:02.155: D/dalvikvm(22760): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
        04-26 18:09:02.157: I/dalvikvm(22760): Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
        04-26 18:09:02.157: W/dalvikvm(22760): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 387: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
        04-26 18:09:02.157: D/dalvikvm(22760): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
        04-26 18:09:02.194: D/ThemeManager(22760): Res_clear()
        04-26 18:09:02.206: W/asset(22760): AssetManager-->addDefaultAssets CIP path not exsit!
        04-26 18:09:02.231: D/AbsListView(22760): checkAbsListViewlLogProperty get invalid command
        04-26 18:09:02.245: V/PhoneWindow(22760): DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4
        04-26 18:09:02.245: D/ServiceManager(22760): The name of the service is input_method
        04-26 18:09:02.251: D/ServiceManager(22760): The name of the service is power
        04-26 18:09:02.257: V/PhoneWindow(22760): DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0
        04-26 18:09:02.276: D/GN_FW_TextView(22760): onMeasure,mLayout=android.text.BoringLayout@41312d60
        04-26 18:09:02.278: D/AndroidRuntime(22760): Shutting down VM
        04-26 18:09:02.279: W/dalvikvm(22760): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d249a8)
        04-26 18:09:02.295: E/AndroidRuntime(22760): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        04-26 18:09:02.295: E/AndroidRuntime(22760): java.lang.NullPointerException
        04-26 18:09:02.295: E/AndroidRuntime(22760):    at com.example.gridviewmapexample.NikAdapter.getView(MainActivity.java:98)
        04-26 18:09:02.295: E/AndroidRuntime(22760):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2207)
        04-26 18:09:02.295: E/AndroidRuntime(22760):    at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1040)
        04-26 18:09:02.295: E/AndroidRuntime(22760):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
        04-26 18:09:02.295: E/AndroidRuntime(22760):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:681)
        04-26 18:09:02.295: E/AndroidRuntime(22760):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
        04-26 18:09:02.295: E/AndroidRuntime(22760):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
        04-26 18:09:02.295: E/AndroidRuntime(22760):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4919)
        04-26 18:09:02.295: E/AndroidRuntime(22760):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        04-26 18:09:02.295: E/AndroidRuntime(22760):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
        04-26 18:09:02.295: E/AndroidRuntime(22760):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4919)
        04-26 18:09:02.295: E/AndroidRuntime(22760):    at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:453)
        04-26 18:09:02.295: E/AndroidRuntime(22760):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
        04-26 18:09:02.295: E/AndroidRuntime(22760):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4919)
        04-26 18:09:02.295: E/AndroidRuntime(22760):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        04-26 18:09:02.295: E/AndroidRuntime(22760):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
        04-26 18:09:02.295: E/AndroidRuntime(22760):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4919)
        04-26 18:09:02.295: E/AndroidRuntime(22760):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1411)
        04-26 18:09:02.295: E/AndroidRuntime(22760):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:698)
        04-26 18:09:02.295: E/AndroidRuntime(22760):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        04-26 18:09:02.295: E/AndroidRuntime(22760):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
        04-26 18:09:02.295: E/AndroidRuntime(22760):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4919)
        04-26 18:09:02.295: E/AndroidRuntime(22760):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        04-26 18:09:02.295: E/AndroidRuntime(22760):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2200)
        04-26 18:09:02.295: E/AndroidRuntime(22760):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
        04-26 18:09:02.295: E/AndroidRuntime(22760):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2165)
        04-26 18:09:02.295: E/AndroidRuntime(22760):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1249)
        04-26 18:09:02.295: E/AndroidRuntime(22760):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1443)
        04-26 18:09:02.295: E/AndroidRuntime(22760):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1139)
        04-26 18:09:02.295: E/AndroidRuntime(22760):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4872)
        04-26 18:09:02.295: E/AndroidRuntime(22760):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
        04-26 18:09:02.295: E/AndroidRuntime(22760):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579)
        04-26 18:09:02.295: E/AndroidRuntime(22760):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:548)
        04-26 18:09:02.295: E/AndroidRuntime(22760):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
        04-26 18:09:02.295: E/AndroidRuntime(22760):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
        04-26 18:09:02.295: E/AndroidRuntime(22760):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        04-26 18:09:02.295: E/AndroidRuntime(22760):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
        04-26 18:09:02.295: E/AndroidRuntime(22760):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5410)
        04-26 18:09:02.295: E/AndroidRuntime(22760):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        04-26 18:09:02.295: E/AndroidRuntime(22760):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        04-26 18:09:02.295: E/AndroidRuntime(22760):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
        04-26 18:09:02.295: E/AndroidRuntime(22760):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
        04-26 18:09:02.295: E/AndroidRuntime(22760):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        04-26 18:09:02.332: I/Process(22760): Sending signal. PID: 22760 SIG: 9
```

Comment: How can the app crash without a runtime error? Do you see anything at all in the logcat?

Comment: thanks..i have corrected the statement

Comment: Ok, so now, what do you see in the logcat? You should post some stack trace here or something to help us help you ;-)

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(22760): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

E/AndroidRuntime(22760): java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Ok, so here you see you have an exception. You see at what line it happened, and actually you should have a whole stack of errors giving the function call stack that lead to your exception. That's what I'm asking here, not just one line of error, but the whole stack trace. (google "stack trace" if you need more info)

Comment: @Joffrey 
well i am new and this word limit thing is not letting me post the trace..i will be glad if you can help in this regard too ;)

Comment: @Joffrey Please find the stack trace above..thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for the log, the stack trace is actually just the part with the "at ..." and the line leading them. In the stack trace, you can see exactly at which line of which file your exception occurred, and also in which method it is.

Comment: So the question is now, which one is line 98 in MainActivity.java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you have posted your stack trace (the rest of the log is not needed, by the way), you should be able to find yourself where your problem occurred.

The stack trace tells you that your NPE (`NullPointerException`) occurs in `getView()` at line 98 in `MainActivity.java`.

I don't know which one line 98 is, but I see a potential problem in `getView()`:

- you want the `LayoutInflater`, but you call `getSystemService(Context.LAUNCHER_APPS_SERVICE)`. You might wanna call `getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)` instead.

Comment: Ctrl-space is fine, just don't forget to read what the auto-complete wrote for you ;-)